# JTable choose other rows and get their data when certain cell is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable. I want to create an event for one cell that if the user clicks on it, he is able to choose one or more rows from the table and the corresponding IDs are saved in that cell.

[image]

So in the example the user would click on "Click here to choose" in row 2 and then click on e.g. row 1 and row 3. The cell "click here to choose" should then be overwritten with something like 1 and 3 afterwards:

[image]

I'm thinking of somehow creating a MouseAdapter Event on click on the cell but I have no real idea how to do it. Any idea how I can approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you definitely need to use MouseAdapter as below(you have the cell if "if condition become true"):

```
jt.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int r = jt.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int c = jt.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (r >= 0 && c >= 0) {
            ......

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) with `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`. In the handler, update the table's model using `setValueAt()` to reflect the change.